# How do I create the center of TouchScreenButton texture in the center of the TouchScreenButton position along with it's shape?

Tags: godot

So, if I create a button using TouchScreenButton and assign a texture to it, the texture will be displayed on the left bottom of the TouchScreenButton position (See image below)

[image]

The TouchScreenButton position is in the top left corner of the rectable

When I don't assign a texture and instead I create a sprite as the child node and assign a texture to it, it will display the texture in the center of TouchScreenButton.

[image]

But the shape is still follows what I have said earlier.

My question, **How do I create the center of TouchScreenButton texture in the center of the TouchScreenButton position along with it's shape?** I want the TouchScreenButton is in the middle of the TouchScreenButton texture.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1.** Go to your `Sprite` node and in the inspector disable `Centered` property in the offset section. This way though you should keep sprite and shape sizes for centers of the area and the texture to match, coz now both the `Sprite` and `Shape` will be to the right bottom of the origin coordinates of the button.

**Solution 2.** Go to your `TouchScreenButton` node and in the inspector enable `Shape Centered` property in the main section. This way you will make both the shape and the sprite to be centered in the origin of the button.